# Emacs 24.5 Can't handle large org files

Tags: org-mode

This is why I ask -- Orgzly on my humble Samsung galaxy S5 can handle a 1.6MB org file with little trouble.

Emacs croaks. I have to kill it and restart. What?!?!?
I also ask because 1.6MB doesn't seem big to me and I have big plans for org-mode, it's a dream come true... almost.

Emacs 24.5.1
Spacemacs 0.200.1 develop
MBA: 1.7Ghz i7, 8GB 1600 DDR3 RAM

Comment: Is this file composed of long lines? Do you have line numbers activated? Does Spacemacs ask you if you want to open the file literally because it is a big file?

Comment: Yes to all 3. The file contains online sessions & bookmarks. So some of the links appear long. There are also many thousands of links.

Comment: What happens if you open the file without org mode? (`M-x fundamental-mode`, or if emacs gets unresponsive as soon as you open the file, rename it to `file.txt` and open it)

Comment: There is no problen in fundemental mode. I was really hoping to use org to organize all this info so it would be a real shame not to.

Comment: prob at 6000 lines http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5377/practical-limits-on-org-mode-file-size. No prob at 17,000 lines, https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-08/msg00137.html. My file - 30,785 lines, my mistake that is large. I turned off line numbering and so far it is behaving. Will update.

Comment: Line numbers. Responsive for most tasks, ie. global visibility cycling. Adjusting entire tree hierarchy on 29,708 line file required ~13 seconds, undo took about same time. I have auto-disabled line numbers for org files with (add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (linenum-mode 0))) [via comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229705/emacs-org-mode-turn-off-line-numbers]. Thanks @syl20bnr et al.

Comment: Have you tried `nlinum-mode`?

Comment: @vv111y I have the same issue with linum and org files, I usually disable linum in org as well. There is a nlinum layer you can try, it is not default because on my machine it introduces key ghosting (I release the key and point continue to move) maybe for you it will work, try it. When you have your solution, post an answer and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @syl20bnr suggested, the issue is with the linum package. I disabled it and emacs is responsive again. I disabled it for org-mode by default by putting the following in init (user-config in spacemacs):

```
 (add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (linenum-mode 0)))
```

(via comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229705/emacs-org-mode-turn-off-line-numbers) ).

Editing the file in a significant way is slow however; modifying the entire tree hierarchy of a 29,708 file requires about 13 seconds. Undo takes about the same time. It still works, but can reduce productivity, so I will adjust my usage with multiple, limited size files.